# How to setup messages in Perl to be processed?

Tags: mysql, perl

What is the best way for a server to process messages in Perl?

I'm trying

```
while ( 1 ) {
  # Get Queue Messages
  # Do Work
  sleep( 10 );
}
```

My mysql schema is of the sort

```
create table message (
  id int auto_increment primary key,
  processed int,
  message varchar(100)
)
```

and in my "#Get Queue Messages", I do a request like

```
select * from message where processed = 0
```

and then flip the flag when it's done.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds to me like what you really want is a *job queue*, like [Gearman](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Gearman::Client) or [TheSchwartz](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?TheSchwartz).

Answer (score 1):

Well, it depends on what these 'messages' are and how far you want to go.  For a lot of circumstances, what you're doing is probably just fine.

If you're using this mechanism for a high volume of interprocess communication traffic between your server and its clients, though, you may be committing an instance of the ['database-as-IPC anti-pattern'](http://wikibin.org/articles/database-as-an-ipc.html).  What's basically meant by that is that it's not a good thing to use a database for routine, high-volume message passing between processes.

If this message table is being used that way, you might want to look into doing a 'proper' IPC implementation.  The [Perl IPC man page](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.8.8/perlipc.html) has plenty of useful information for this.

Comment: They're mostly requests from apache/web, which I'm trying to offload to a daemon.

I also intend to keep all these messages though, will this scale?

Comment: It won't scale very well to large numbers of messages, no.  Whether it's workable depends on how many messages you're actually going to process.  It's probably a good idea to do monthly message tables instead of a single one, or even daily if this is going to be a real high-volume application.  Or, of course, you could use non-database IPC mechanisms like I refer to, for telling the daemon directly what you want to have processed.  If you want/need a permanent record of the messages, though, then pushing them into a database is appropriate.